# Using MultiValuedMap with Jackson

Tags: java, spring-boot, serialization, jackson

Hello I am trying to create an object from the following json :

```
    {
    "property1": "value1",
    "property2": [
        {"key1":"value1"},
        {"key1":"value2"},
        {"key2":"value1"}
    ]
}
```

The reason am using MultiValuedMap is because the keys in property 2 can be duplicates (as for the values).

The problem is that jackson throws an error when I try something like this :

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@Builder
@EqualsAndHashCode
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class MyClass {
    
    private String property1;

    private List<MultiValuedMap<String, String>> property2;

}
```

As for the controller it's like this :

```
@PostMapping(value = "update")
MyClass saveMyClass(@RequestBody @Valid MyClass myClass);
```

but when trying to send the json to my api it gives the following error :

> org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException:
> Type definition error: [simple type, class
> org.apache.commons.collections4.MultiValuedMap]; nested exception is
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot
> construct instance of `org.apache.commons.collections4.MultiValuedMap`
> (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): abstract types either
> need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or
> contain additional type information

Comment: Have you tried using implementation ArrayListValuedHashMap instead? So make it List<ArrayListValuedHashMap<String,String>> property2. The error complains about no constructor for the interface...

Comment: @Jan I just did and it doesn't throw the error anymore but the list is empty, it does not contain any values.

Comment: The result is this : [{}, {}, {}]. There is the 3 ArrayListValuedHashMap but the <String, String> is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a List<Map.Entry<String,String>> ?

This works right out of the box and if you really want to use a MuliValuedMap you can convert the List into one with the following sniped:

```java
var map = new ArrayListValuedHashMap<String, String>();
result.property2.stream()
                        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey))
                        .entrySet()
                        .forEach(entry ->
                                         map.putAll(entry.getKey(),
                                                    entry.getValue().stream().map(Map.Entry::getValue).toList()));
```